# Does reuse storage start lifetime of a new object?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, struct

```
#include <cstdlib>
struct B {
    virtual void f();
    void mutate();
    virtual ~B();
};
struct D1 : B { void f(); };
struct D2 : B { void f(); };
void B::mutate() {
    new (this) D2; // reuses storage — ends the lifetime of *this
    f(); // undefined behavior - WHY????
    ... = this; // OK, this points to valid memory
}
```

I need to be explained why `f()` invokation has UB? `new (this) D2;` reuses storage, but it also call a constructor for `D2` and since starts lifetime of a new object. In that case `f()` equals to `this -> f()`. **That is we just call `f()` member function of `D2`.** Who knows why it is UB?

Comment: Placement-new is supposed to be used on most derived classes, and replacing them with objects of the same type. This is another reason you have UB, because not only are you replacing a base class subobject, you are replacing it with an object of a different type.

Comment: @0x499602D2 18.6.1.3 of the Standard defines behavior of such placement-new, but not says anything about supposing to be used **on most derived classes, and creating objects of the same type.**

Comment: 3.8 "If, after the lifetime of an object has ended […], a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, […] the name of the original object […] will automatically refer to the new object […] and can be used to manipulate the new object […] if: the original object was a most derived object (1.8) of type T and the new object is a most derived object of type T (that is, they are not base class subobjects)."

Comment: @0x499602D2 But I don't explcitly call a destructor, since the lifetime of the original object hasn't ended. In the example to the quote that you cited it is pretty clear, because we explcitly call destrcutor before.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that after I posted the comment. That quote may be irrelevant. Sorry.

Comment: @St.Antario: Of course the lifetime of the original object has ended.  Memory for it no longer exists; it has been reused.

Comment: @BenVoigt Why? The lifetime of an object has not been ended at the time we reuse the memory. The quote you cited doesn't cover that case, I think. I really have been trying to understand that...

Comment: @St.Antario: The Standard says "**A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies** or by explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor."  It doesn't matter whether the object is alive right before you reuse its memory; afterward it definitely is not.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, I've understood. Thank you. But more formally it is not true, Right? I mean, it doesn't imply from the 3.8/7 in a **formal** way that it can be apply to the case when the lifetime of an object hasn't been ended. Moreover, the Standard provides an example which explcitly **end of lifetime by the destructor call**. It adds more confusion I think.

Comment: @St.Antario: Calling the destructor is sufficient for ending the object lifetime, but not necessary.

Comment: Even if calling the dtor was mandatory, then what? There is nothing in the std that allows you to construct an object and then use old, stale ptr (`this` is old and stale at that point) except the quoted text. So you better hope "If, after the lifetime of an object has ended […], a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, […] the name of the original object" applies, or else, you have nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard shows this example § 3.8 67 N3690:

```
struct C {
  int i;
  void f();
  const C& operator=( const C& );
};

const C& C::operator=( const C& other) {
  if ( this != &other ) {
    this->~C(); // lifetime of *this ends
    new (this) C(other); // new object of type C created
    f(); // well-defined
  }
  return *this;
}

C c1;
C c2;
c1 = c2; // well-defined
c1.f(); // well-defined; c1 refers to a new object of type C
```

Notice that this example is terminating the lifetime of the object before constructing the new object in-place (compare to your code, which does not call the destructor).

But even if you did, the standard also says:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage
>   which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is
>   created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a
>   pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred
>   to the original object, or the name of the original object will
>   automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the
>   new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> — the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location
>   which the original object occupied, and — the new object is of the
>   same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level
>   cv-qualifiers), and
>
> — the type of the original object is not
>   const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static
>   data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and
>
> — the original object was a most derived object (1.8) of type T and the
>   new object is a most derived object of type T (that is, they are not
>   base class subobjects).

notice the 'and' words, the above conditions must all be fulfilled.

Since you're not fulfilling all the conditions (you have a derived object in-placed into the memory space of a base class object), you have *undefined behavior* when referencing stuff with an implicit or explicit use of this pointer.

Depending on the compiler implementation this might or might now blow because a base class virtual object reserves some space for the **vtable**, **in-place constructing an object of a derived type which overrides some of the virtual functions means the vtable might be different**, put alignment issues and other low-level internals and you'll have that a simple sizeof won't suffice to determine if your code is right or not.

Comment: Are you saying he isn't terminating the lifetime of the old object?  The Standard says that he is.

Comment: He isn't destructing the object, which could be terribly bad. I'll specify this for correctness sake, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This construct is very interesting:

- The placement-new is not guaranteed to call the destructor of the object. So this code will not properly ensure end of life of the object.
- So in principle you should call the destructor before reusing the object.  But then you would continue to execute a member function of an object that is dead.  According to standard section.9.3.1/2 *If a non-static member function of a class X is called for an object that is not of type X, or of a type derived from X, the behavior is undefined.*
- If you don't explicitely delete your object, as you do in your code, you then recreate a new object (constructing a second B without destoying the first one, then D2 ot top of this new B).

When the creation of your new object is finished, the identity of your current object has in fact changed while executing the function.  You cannot be sure if the pointer to the virtual function that will be called was read before your placement-new (thus the old pointer to D1::f) or after (thus D2::f).

By the way, it's exactly for this reason, that there are some constraints about what you can or can't do in a union, where a same memory place is shared for different active objects (see Point 9.5/2 and perticularly point 9.5/4 in the standard).

Comment: Placement new won't clean up the old object, but it will kill it.  An object's lifetime ends if its memory is reused.

Comment: Yes, true:  once overwritten, the old object will no longer show sign of life !  However *"after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused"* strongly suggest that in principle, the end of life should happen before the reuse, and point 9.5/4 demonstrate this in another context.  This is why I formulated *"will not **properly** ensure"*. For example if object would use smart pointers, these would be bluntly overwritten, and their reference count will be wrong: the using object might get killed, but it could still haunt the code !

Comment: That "*after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused*" is a fancy way of saying *while the destructor is running, if you choose to run it*.  The line that "*after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied*" is a nod to the fact that memory doesn't physically go away.  You could "release" it with `free()` but your libc still owns it and will give it back to you via `malloc()`.

Comment: I think that rule is also making it illegal to put type `A` in a memory location, make a pointer to it, then put type `B` there, then put another type `A` there and use the original pointer.  The fact that the memory location was reused for a type `B` irrevocably breaks the original `A*`.